# How to disconnect from MutationObserver if the child element that you are checking for is never generated

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, mutation-observers

I have this code that waits for a specific `HTMLElement` to load inside some parent element. I achieved this with the `MutationObserver` that triggers everytime `childList` of parent element is changed. When the element is created it selects all of the text inside of it and disconnects the observer. **But what if the element is never created? What would be the best way to disconnect the observer?**

current code:

```
selectTextOnEdit(cell: HTMLTableCellElement) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(mutation => {
        if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
          const inputElement = cell.querySelector('input');
          if (inputElement) {
            inputElement.select();
            observer.disconnect();
          }
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(cell, {childList: true});
  }
```

Comment: You could use a timeout, or disconnect it in ngOnDestroy. Could you explain why do need to use `MutationObserver` using Angular?

Comment: I use a 3rd party component which on click triggers onCellEdit event... but when the event triggers the input element is not yet generated so I have to wait for it to generate. Why I want to disconnect is... is because I can add a custom cell edit template which might not contain an input element.

Comment: I know I can solve this with a timeout.. but I don't like timeouts because I'm writing code in client dependent language... and execution times vary from client to client

Comment: There are no other universal solutions. You could expose some function to cancel the wait explicitly.